# PHP range issues with number starting with 0

Tags: php

```
$ids = range(000,010);
```

gives same results as

```
$ids = range(0,10);
```

In short it avoids zeros in the beginning. I want to include the zero for my requirements.
I would like to use this function to range from 000-999, how can I do that ?

Comment: Integers dont have leading zeros in any computer language. If you want that you will have to convert the numerics to a string after the range statement

Comment: Your `000` should be in the display part not processing part. If I `echo 000;` or many zero leading the result will always be `0`. Convert `0` to `000` on your display part only.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the output.

```
$ids = array_map(fn($value) => sprintf('%03d', $value), range(0,10));
print_r($ids);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000
    [1] => 001
    [2] => 002
    [3] => 003
    [4] => 004
    [5] => 005
    [6] => 006
    [7] => 007
    [8] => 008
    [9] => 009
    [10] => 010
)
```